# Can someone explain me how the "empty statement" in javaScript is affected from "Automatic Semicolon Insertion"

Tags: javascript, automatic-semicolon-insertion

Can someone explain me how the **"empty statement"** in javaScript is affected from **"Automatic Semicolon Insertion"** The [MDN website states that the **empty statement is affected from automatic semicolon insertion**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)
though its not stated in the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion)
can anyone explain this to me and can anyone explain me what is the difference between a **semicolon** and an **empty statement**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the spec linked from the MDN page. The empty statement is "affected" because ASI won't be done if the inserted semicolon would result in an empty statement.

Hand-wringing over when ASI happens can be dispensed with by simply including semicolons explicitly. The most common pitfall of ASI is the `return` statement, when attempting something like

```
return
  { propertyName: "something" };
```

Don't do that. Start the object initializer on the same line as the `return`.

As to the difference between a semicolon and an empty statement: a semicolon is a boundary. In the following code:

```
var x; ;
```

There's a `var` declaration statement, then an empty statement. The second semicolon is not *part* of the empty statement, but it implies that there *is* an empty statement before it.

Comment: but i dont think the first **semicolon** you wrote after the **var x** statement is an empty statement i think its also a *semicolon*

Comment: Yes, every semicolon is a semicolon. They **separate** statements.

Comment: then what is an **empty statement** [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-EmptyStatement) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty) talks about

Comment: The empty statement is what's between the two semicolons. It's kind-of a zen thing.

Comment: what's between the two semicolons though there in only a whitepace character ? `var x; ;`

Comment: Exactly. Why do you think the "empty statement" is called the "empty statement"?

Comment: but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty) and the [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-EmptyStatement) specification haven't stated that a `whitespace` is what known as the `empty statement` but they have stated that the `semicolon` is the empty statement

Comment: @Kevin no. The empty statement is the lack of anything other than whitespace between two semicolons. Thus, with `var x = 1;;` there's also an empty statement. You're misreading the article on MDN; really the spec itself is the authoritative source of information. On top of that, learning the language by examining the minutiae of its grammar is a really bad idea. Nobody programming in JavaScript on a daily basis worries about what an "empty statement" is.

Comment: okay i found that the "semicolon" is not a statement all by itself